# bootstrap col push pull using mobile version

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

[image: bootstrap col push pull]

top: desktop version bottom: mobile version.
I would like to move div A to bottom of the page when the mobile size(col-xs).
I'd tried to solve this problem but I couldn't.
Let me know I can use CSS or JavaScript if I can't use the push and pull function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible with Bootstrap's built in classes. It is possible with CSS3 using Flexbox OR with jQuery.

I'm not great with jQuery, but you could could do this:

```
function moveA() {
    if ($(window).width < 768) {
        $(".a").insertAfter(".c");
    } else {
        $(".a").insertBefore(".b");
    }
}

$( window ).resize(function() { moveA }
```

This will fire the moveA function every time the window is resized. moveA figures out if the screen is at your desired width and then moves A either after C or before B.

With CSS3 using Flexbox, you can set your container for the items to `display:flex` and in your media queries change

```
@media screen and (max-width:768) {
    .a {
        order: 2;
     }
}
```

There's a little more to it than that, but you can see the Flexbox solution here:

http://codepen.io/tinyglowstudio/pen/meEYNB

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do it . Push the a beyond c. In this way the mid section will take its full width . Increase the width of both ather two in small device.
I do same in the website 
http://cyborgcreation.in to adjust the banner image contact info and social buttons.